# Unable to scrape some timestamp attached to a text from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a [timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxZDM.jpg) attached to a text from a webpage. I can grab the text flawlessly but can't find out the timestamp. I can scrape the other timestamps attached to the comments from there, though. The timestamps which are with the comments can be found in the script tag as the value of `created_at`. However, I can't find the one I'm after.

[website url](https://www.instagram.com/p/CEuX_8iH95S/)

I've tried with:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CEuX_8iH95S/'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(url)
    script_tag = json.loads(re.findall(r"window\._sharedData = (.*?});",r.text)[0])
    post_content = script_tag['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node']['text']
    print(post_content)
```

How can I parse the timestamp attached to the text from the site above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the timestamp with `.fromtimestamp()` method from the `datetime` module.

Here's how to do it:

```
import datetime
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CEuX_8iH95S/'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(url)
    script_tag = json.loads(re.findall(r'window\._sharedData = (.*?});', r.text)[0])
    post_date = script_tag['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['taken_at_timestamp']

    print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(post_date).isoformat())
    print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(post_date).strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

This prints:

```
2020-09-04T20:25:49
Sep 04 2020 20:25:49
```

If you want to learn more about date formatting, check the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Your solution appears to be working except for the fact that there is a slight variation between the date in that site and the one your suggested script is producing. Given that it is `sep 05` in there. Thanks.